# (DOM cannot be used) Javascript regular expressions match text and filter HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I need to use a regular expression to replace "text" in the text, but not the HTML tag attribute value "text".

Note: I know the various DOM manipulations, but my needs don't fit the DOM, so I can only use regular expressions here. I'm sorry.

---

Javascript code:

```js
var str = '"text<div id="text">is text istext"text"</div> text '
var xxx = str.replace(/([\s.?,"';:!()\[\]{}<>/])(text)([\s.?,"';:!()\[\]{}<>/])/g, '$1xxxx$3');
console.log(xxx)
```

---

See the following example:

The wrong   result is:

`"xxxx<div id="xxxx">is xxxx istext"xxxx"</div> xxxx` 
(This is the result of my code)

The correct result is:

`"xxxx<div id="text">is xxxx istext"xxxx"</div> xxxx` 
(`id="text"` stays the same here)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the one reason you *must* use RegExp over a DOMParser? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: That's not valid html, quotes must be html encoded.

Comment: Why should it not match `text` in `istext`?

Comment: Because all the words I need to give website span tags, I use the dom manipulation such as ` document. CreateTreeWalker () ` met a bigger problem, I think after comparing the regular expression is the best solution.

Comment: Because I need to match words (strings with gaps between them), 'istext' is not a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?<=(^|>)[^<>]*)\btext\b/g
```

**Explanation**:

`(?<=` - look behind

`(^|>)` - for start of text OR a greater than sign `>`

`[^<>]*` - followed by zero or more of any character not being `<>`

`)` - end of look behind

`\btext\b` - match a word break followed be `text` and another word break

It's using the `global` flag.

Now replace with `xxxx` or whatever.

You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/LX6UwH/1

Comment: Thank you. The result of this code is`"xxxx$3<div id="text">is >xxxx$3 istext">xxxx$3"</div> >xxxx$3 `,Much better, but not quite in line with demand.

Comment: You use the wrong replacement string, delete `$3` from it.

Comment: I did, and now the answer is better, but still not close to the right answer. The code result is`"xxxx<div id="text">is >xxxx istext">xxxx"</div> >xxxx `, the correct result should be `"xxxx<div id="text">is xxxx istext"xxxx"</div> xxxx `

Comment: You should ONLY have `xxxx` in the replacement. Whatever you write there will be the value - see the regex101.com link.

Comment: Well, it was a bit of a problem, but it taught me a lot about regular expressions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it would be a lot simpler/reliable to break this into two distinct steps. The first step splits the html into tag contents, the second transforms the contents (if needed).

```
var s = '"text<div id="text">is text istext"text"</div> text ';
var r = s.split(/([<>])/); // split into array of parts
r.map(function(segment, index, all){
 if(segment=="<") this.inTag = 1;
 if(segment==">") this.inTag = 0;
 if(this.inTag) return segment; // return markup unchanged
 return segment.replace(/([\s.?,"';:!()\[\]{}<>/])(text)([\s.?,"';:!()\[\]{}<>/])/g, '$1xxxx$3');
 
},{inTag:0})
.join(""); // == "text<div id="text">is xxxx istext"xxxx"</div> xxxx
```

it looks like you need to tweak your regexp to match the first part, i just used your version, but that should be a lot simpler since you don't have to worry about trying to avoid tags markup using regexp markup.

Of course, the usual caveats and warnings about "parsing" html with RegExp apply (eg tag-looking markup in script tags), but this should be a lot easier to work with if you absolutely positively cannot use a real DOM to manipulate the content.

Comment: Great. I didn't think we could handle them separately. But the words AND HTML pages I'm replacing are so large that I don't know if it will affect efficiency. If there is no other way, I will use this method. Thank you